# After execution of simple program on netbeans getting output in different language

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

[image: output image]

After execution of simple program on netbeans getting output in different language. please find below screenshot.

I am expecting the output in English language.

Comment: It's probably in the language settings for the IDE, but overall this isn't really a programming problem (as much as it is a problem of _using_ software). There is also no screenshot in your post.

Comment: yes. let me edit the question.

Comment: are you able to see it now?

Comment: You're missing a font or the font that you're using is corrupted, likely the Segoe UI font.

Comment: And that is no human language that I know of, but rather it is simply text displayed with a garbled font.

Comment: how I can fix it?

Comment: You should include (as text) the code you used to generate the issue.

Comment: Thank you guys, issue resolved. thanks @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: Off-topic: the javafx-maven-plugin version 0.0.4 that you are using is outdated and obsolete (the current version is 0.0.8).  Always use up-to-date software versions for all software dependencies, runtime platforms, and development tools, especially when experiencing weird behavior such as that displayed in your question.  Oftentimes such behavior is due to bugs that are resolved in recent software versions.